# How to count multiple case statements including the final "if" statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have a question that asks to calculate the number of orders based on several conditions:-

1. Device Type "A" AND Price < $2
2. Device Type "A" AND Price BETWEEN $2-3
3. Device Type "B" AND Price > $3
4. Everything else as "others"

Sample query to answer the question as follows:-

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN Device Type = "A" AND Price < 2 THEN '1' END),
COUNT(CASE WHEN Device Type = "A" AND Price IN (2,3) THEN '1' END),
COUNT(CASE WHEN Device Type = "B" AND Price > 3 THEN '1' END)
FROM table
```

**My question is: how do I count that last condition (4) for everything else as "others"?** (for example, it could be Device Type A but more than $3 or Device Type B but less than $3)

I am a beginner SQL user, so I apologize if this seems like a straightforward answer that's staring at me in the face.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN DeviceType = 'A' AND Price < 2 THEN '1' END),
COUNT(CASE WHEN DeviceType = 'A' AND Price IN (2,3) THEN '1' END),
COUNT(CASE WHEN DeviceType = 'B' AND Price > 3 THEN '1' END),
COUNT(CASE WHEN (DeviceType = 'A' AND Price < 2)
    OR (DeviceType = 'A' AND Price IN (2,3))
    OR (DeviceType = 'B' AND Price > 3) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END)
FROM yourTable;
```